# Having more than 2 logical drives in a HP ML350 G6

Tags: raid, hp, hp-smart-array

I've begun setup of a HP ML350 G6 and I've hit a wall. I've got 2 RAID drives (each having 2 HDDs  in a mirror). I've now come to put a couple of extra disks into the server and it won't let me create the logical disks for the 2 new drives. I don't want to RAID them, just have them appear as normal disks.

When I try to add them from the RAID utility (F8 during boot) I get a message saying ORCA can't handle any more logical drives, and that I should use the array config utility to add them. I tried using the array config to add them but can't see how to do it. The disks are both picked up and labeled "un-allocated" but I can't find any way to allocate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to purchase a memory module for the RAID controller, as contrllers with no memory only allow to create 2 arrays :-)

Comment: where would i be able to get one?

Comment: just contact any HP reseller (or if feeling brave, you can try ebay :-P)

Answer (score 0):

The P410i controller you have in that machine can support up to 64 logicial drives/arrays - you have to define an array to put the allocated disks into, they can't just be on their own, they have to be part of a RAID array even if they're the only member.

Comment: ok... but how do i do that? The only thing i can find that indocates it will do anything with the disks is adding them as spare drives to existing arrays

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should check that you have the latest version of firmware and driver installed: first download and install the latest Support Pack (or equivalent of your OS) and then run Firmware Maintenance CD. It is important that in an upgrade scenario you update the drivers **before** the firmware.

Then you can run the Array Configuration Utility (ACU) to create a new raidset and then a logical volume.

Answer (score 0):

The ACU should give you an option to create a RAID array, but you have to click on the controller to get that option, not on a physical drive.

If you are still having problems, make sure your controller firmware and your ACU software are fully up-to-date.  Newer versions of ACU also have a "Wizard" tab that can automate some of these configuration steps.